# Вывод в Clion принтов - если способ убрать ограничения

Tags: c++, clion

При работе кода в Clion кодом на с++ выводится большое кол-во принтов Print(a, m). Но чем больше выводим, тем больше исчезает из нижнего окошка. Вопрос - можно ли сделать так чтобы там отображались и сохранялись все принты от 1 до последнего значения даже если их там миллион.

Ниже пример на котором после выполнения кода значения оказались только от 320718-ой строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Миллион? Не задумывались над выводом в файл?

Comment: Конечен ли вывод и какая ОС у вас?

Comment: ¿А почему бы тогда просто не печатать все, что идет до 320718 строки? ¿Неужели вы все это читаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Размер буфера консоли задается в

Settings → Editor → General → Console → Override console cycle buffer size

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако выводить тонны текста - обычно не очень продуктивное занятие.
Кроме того, clion испытывает сложности с отображением больших объемов текста. Так что если уж нужно много печатать, то имеет смысл выводить в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ не совсем на поставленный вопрос. Clion в директории проекта создаст ещё одну директорию с названием `cmake-build-debug`, в ней будет лежать ваш исполняемый файл. Открываете там терминал (powerShell в вашем случае) и пишете что-то вида: `./*тут подставить имя вашего исполняемого файла* > *имя файла для вывода*`. Когда программа отработает она всё выведет в этот файл. Консоль но идее будет доступна из самого CLion.
А вообще это можно всё сделать в самой программе.
В консоле по директориям можно ходить командой cd